# mysql search order by distance is slow

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, distance

```
set @dist = 100;
set @rlng1 = 48.67607474000000-@dist/abs(cos(radians(31.34747060000000))*69);
set @rlng2 = 48.67607474000000+@dist/abs(cos(radians(31.34747060000000))*69);
set @rlat1 = 31.34747060000000-(@dist/69);
set @rlat2 = 31.34747060000000+(@dist/69);

SELECT name,storeId, ST_DISTANCE(POINT(48.67607474000000,31.34747060000000),
                                 POINT(lng, lat)) AS distance
FROM store
WHERE ST_WITHIN(POINT(48.67607474000000,31.34747060000000),
                ENVELOPE(LINESTRING(point(@rlng1, @rlat1),
                         point(@rlng2, @rlat2))))
ORDER by distance
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

i have a query to get near user store ..

this is my query .. when i run query normally without  ( ORDER by distance ) my query run in 0.0161 seconds But when i use ( ORDER by distance ) my query run in  2.8791 seconds .

what should i do to get best run time on my query have order by distance ?

Answer (score 1):

Without `ORDER BY`, it will look at 10 rows, compute the stuff, and deliver the results.

With `ORDER BY`, it will look at *all* rows, compute stuff for *all* of them, sort the results, and *finally* deliver the first 10.

What indexes do you have?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.